# What's the point of inject decorator if Provider is said to be already passing all the props down to all the children?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

Consider a case:

```
import { Provider } from 'mobx-react';
import usersStore from './stores/usersStore';
import itemsStore from './stores/itemsStore';

const stores = { usersStore, itemsStore };

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider {...stores}>
    <SomeComponent />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

So, doesn't `SomeComponent` in the sample above already get both `usersStore` and `itemsStore` as its `props` from `Provider`? Why is the `@inject('itemsStore')` line in the following sample even required?

```
@inject('itemsStore') @observer
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="index">
        {this.props.itemsStore.items.map((item, index) => {
          return <span key={index}>item.name</span>
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Provider is a component that can pass stores (or other stuff) using
>   React's context mechanism to child components. This is useful if you
>   have things that you don't want to pass through multiple layers of
>   components explicitly.
>
> inject can be used to pick up those stores. It is a higher order
>   component that takes a list of strings and makes those stores
>   available to the wrapped component.

`Provider` and `inject` are abstractions to React [`context` API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) (which until recently was quite unstable).

The Provider makes data available from components context, while `inject` HOC provides a simple API to declare what we want out of the context and passes it to the wrapper component.

The same works other libraries like `react-redux`.

Comment: Do you mean that I won't obtain `itemsStore` in the props of `SomeComponent` by using only `Provider` part?

Comment: @jayarjo True. It is only available by a context at that point. The second part is to get it out of the context and pass it down to the component as a prop - it's the job of `inject` HOC.